# Using Regex for complicated naming convention

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm writing a Computer naming convention validation PowerShell script. I'm following a documentation my client provided. My first path I went down was to break each computer name into bits and process each part, but I seem to have issues near the end. I was thinking it would be easier to just use one regex to ensure its valid. Here is what I am trying to do

Naming rules:

- Required: 1st is an alpha character; must be: **A**,**B**, or **C**
- Required: 2nd s an alpha character; must be: **L**,**K**, or **H**
- Required: The next **4** characters must be alpha and match either: **DTLB**,**SOCK**, or **NUUB**
- Required: The next **6** characters are digits but the first part can either be: **1**, **8**, **13**, or **83**; the rest doesn't matter as long as they are digits
- Optional: The next two characters can be alpha or alpha numeric but must be either: **PE**, **Y1**, or **AC**

Here are some tests with a regex that I understand, which is basic but works. It doesn't validate the actual characters or position, it just checks the first 12 characters and if there are two alphas characters at the end:

```
$regex = '^\w{12}(?:\w{2})$|^\w{12}$'
'AKDTLB123456' -match $regex; $Matches
True
'ALSOCK834561PE' -match $regex; $Matches
True
```

What I am trying to do is split these up into named parts and determine if the value matches the right area like (this is an example):

```
$regex = '(<type>^\w{1}[ABC])(?<form>\w{1,1}[LKH])(<locale>\w{4,4}[DTLB|SOCK|NUUB])(<identifier>\d{1,1}[1|8]|<identifier>\d{1,2}[13|83])(<unique>\d+)(<role>\w{2,2}[PE|AC]$|<role>\w{1}[Y]\d{1}$)'
```

My goal is to get it to output like this:
Example 1

```
'AKDTLB893456' -match $regex; $Matches
True
Name                           Value                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
----                           -----                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
type                          A                                                                                                                                                                                                           
form                          K 
locale                        DTLB
identifier                    1
Unique                        23456
0                             AKDTLB893456
```

Example 2:

```
'ALSOCK123456PE' -match $regex; $Matches
True
 Name                           Value                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
 ----                           -----                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
 type                          A                                                                                                                                                                                                           
 form                          L 
 locale                        SOCK
 identifier                    1
 Unique                        23456
 0                             ALSOCK123456PE
```

Example 3

```
'ALSUCK123456PE' -match $regex; $Matches
False
 Name                           Value                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
 ----                           -----                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
 type                          A                                                                                                                                                                                                           
 form                          L 
 locale                                   <--not matched
 identifier                    1
 Unique                        23456
 0                             ALSuCK123456PE
```

The best I can do is:

```
$regex = '(^\w{1})(\w{1,1})(\w{4,4})(\d{2}[13|83]|\d{1}[1|2|3])(\d{4,5})(\w{2,2}$|$)'
'ALSOCK124561PE' -match $regex; $Matches
True

Name                           Value                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
----                           -----                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
6                              PE                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
5                              4561                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
4                              12                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
3                              SOCK                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
2                              L                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
1                              A                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
0                              ALSOCK834561PE
```

However this doesn't check for if the name is just **1**12345 not **13**

I have been all over the internet and using the regex online tool, but am unable to come up with a solution. This may not be possible to do both. I find if the value is false, its not outputting the one that match and not the rest. Is there a way to get the *"why it doesn't match"* as an output?

Any ideas?

Comment: so basically you have 2 questions? The first question is for a regex that matches your rules, and the second question is for some logic that outputs the reasons why the regex did not match in case of mismatch?

Comment: I would use this pattern `[ABC][LKH](DTLB|SOCK|NUUB)[1|8]\d{5}(PE|Y1|AC)?`. These requirements  `he first part can either be: 1, 8, 13, or 83` overlap, because 18+(4 any digita) is contained in 1 +(5 any digits), the same is for 8 and 83.

Comment: If the left-hand side of `-match` is a single string, then `$true` is returned when the entire RHS is matched. It returns `$false` otherwise. `$matches` contains updated data when `-match` returns `$true`. `$matches` remains untouched when `$false` is returned (it keeps its previous value). If you want to know where matching fails, then you should create multiple regex strings to test against or feed it into another tool with the capability. If the LHS is an array or collection, `$matches` is not updated and it returns the items from the array that match.

Comment: AL`SUCK`123456PE wonrt match since `SUCK` is not one of the strings in **DTLB, or  SOCK, or NUUB** so a typo, yes ? Anyway, regex for specs is `^(?'typ'[ABC])(?'form'[LKH])(?'loc'DTLB|SOCK|NUUB)(?=[0-9]{6}(?:[PYA]|$))(?'id'[18]3?)(?'uniq'[0-9]{4,5})(?:PE|Y1|AC)?$`

Comment: Right I didn't mean to ask two question. As I was typing the post, it just came to mind. I figured I would need to check using multiple regex or some way. Could I do a [^D-Z] to get what's not matched? Thanks for the input. I did run the regex you specified but it only produces 3 matches, however I see what you mean when  populating the digits. I was stuck on that part as well.

Comment: flags count https://rextester.com/tester/THU12289

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The second part of your question asked if you could determine where the match failed. You can do something similar to below to test each part of the regex in sections starting from the left:

```
$strings = 'AKDTLB893456','ALSOCK123456PE','ALSuCK123456PE','ALSOCK123456R2'
$regexes = [ordered]@{}
$regexes.Add('type','^(?<type>[ABC])')
$regexes.Add('form','(?<form>[LKH])')
$regexes.Add('locale','(?<locale>DTLB|SOCK|NUUB)')
$regexes.Add('identifier','(?<identifier>[18])')
$regexes.Add('unique','(?<unique>\d{5})')
$regexes.Add('optional','(?<optional>PE|Y1|AC)?$')

foreach ($string in $strings) {
    $test = [text.stringbuilder]''
    $regexes.GetEnumerator() | Foreach-Object {
        $null = $test.Append($_.Value)
    if (!($string -match $test.ToString())) {
        "$String failed at $($_.Key)"
        Continue
    }
    }
    $matches
}
```

**Explanation:**

`$regexes` is an ordered hash table where we can append some key-value pairs. Order is good here because we want to test matching from left to right in your string.

With a `[Text.StringBuilder]` object, we can append strings with the `Append()` method. The idea is to append the new regex string you want to test. If `$string` continues to match through each value of the hash table, `$matches` will output. Otherwise, the failed match will cause the current, testing `$regex` key value to output.

---

Note that this will not perform as well as a single `-match` operation. You could test the entire match first and only perform sectional testing when a `$false` is returned. That will increase performance.

Comment: Yes. This does answer the second part and its really shorter than my code (by like 400 lines) ..lol. Perfect. This will work. Thanks!

Comment: I didn't mean to down vote. I actually said it was useful, but for some reason it went to -2. I wish I could give an answer to a two part question.

Comment: @powershellcrack FYI, you can undo a downvote (or an upvote) in two cases. 1) within 5 minutes without restrictions. 2) after 5 minutes if the post is edited. The post appears to have been edited after your downvote (after your last comment). Feel free to undo if it was accidental.

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
^(?<type>[ABC])(?<form>[LKH])(?<locale>DTLB|SOCK|NUUB)(?<identifier>[18](3)?)(?<unique>\d{4}(?(1)|\d))(?<role>PE|Y1|AC)?$
```

**Note**: If the pattern must be matched in a case sensitive way, replace `-match` with `-cmatch`.

See the [.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E%28%3F%3Ctype%3E%5BABC%5D%29%28%3F%3Cform%3E%5BLKH%5D%29%28%3F%3Clocale%3EDTLB%7CSOCK%7CNUUB%29%28%3F%3Cidentifier%3E%5B18%5D%283%29%3F%29%28%3F%3Cunique%3E%5Cd%7B4%7D%28%3F%281%29%7C%5Cd%29%29%28%3F%3Crole%3EPE%7CY1%7CAC%29%3F%5Cr%3F%24&i=AKDTLB893456%0D%0AALSOCK123456PE%0D%0AALSOCK832345AC&o=m) (do not test at regex101.com!)

**Details**

- `^` - start of a string
- `(?<type>[ABC])` - Group "type": `A`, `B` or `C`
- `(?<form>[LKH])` - Group "type": `L`, `K` or `H`
- `(?<locale>DTLB|SOCK|NUUB)`  - Group "locale": `DTLB`, `SOCK` or `NUUB`
- `(?<identifier>[18](3)?)` - Group "identifier": `1` or `8` and then an optional `3` digit *captured into Group **1***
- `(?<unique>\d{4}(?(1)|\d))` - Group "unique": four digits and if Group 1 did not match, one more digit is required to match then
- `(?<role>PE|Y1|AC)?` - an optional Group "role": `PE`, `Y1` or `AC`
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! I have tested this with some other sample names and this matched perfectly. Thanks you for breaking down the regex; very helpful.